# How to update the listbox to scroll downward off line

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm doing Dictionary wp8.1. Very large data dictionary, so I have updated slowly while surfing down. People can help me!!! And how to event?

Thanks!!!
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ListBoxDemo.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(ListBoxDemo_Loaded);
        AddDummyItems();
    }

```
void ListBoxDemo_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    element.Loaded -= ListBoxDemo_Loaded;
    scrollViewer = FindChildOfType<ScrollViewer>(element);
    if (scrollViewer == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("ScrollViewer not found.");
    }

    Binding binding = new Binding();
    binding.Source = scrollViewer;
    binding.Path = new PropertyPath("VerticalOffset");
    binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
    SetBinding(ListVerticalOffsetProperty, binding);
}

private static void OnListVerticalOffsetChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MainPage page = obj as MainPage;
    ScrollViewer viewer = page.scrollViewer;

    //Checks if the Scroll has reached the last item based on the ScrollableHeight
    bool atBottom = viewer.VerticalOffset >= viewer.ScrollableHeight-50;

    if (atBottom)
    {
        //ViewModel will be better........
        int Count = page.ListBoxDemo.Items.Count;
        int end = Count + 20;
        for (int i = Count; i < end; i++)
        {
            page.ListBoxDemo.Items.Add("Dummy Item " + i);
        }
    }
}

void AddDummyItems()
{
    int Count = ListBoxDemo.Items.Count;

    int end = Count + 20;
    for (int i = Count; i < end; i++)
    {
        ListBoxDemo.Items.Add("Dummy Item " + i);
    }
}

public readonly DependencyProperty ListVerticalOffsetProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ListVerticalOffset", typeof(double), typeof(MainPage),
    new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnListVerticalOffsetChanged)));

public double ListVerticalOffset
{
    get { return (double)this.GetValue(ListVerticalOffsetProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(ListVerticalOffsetProperty, value); }
}

/// <summary>
/// Finding the ScrollViewer
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
/// <param name="root"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
static T FindChildOfType<T>(DependencyObject root) where T : class
{
    var queue = new Queue<DependencyObject>();
    queue.Enqueue(root);

    while (queue.Count > 0)
    {
        DependencyObject current = queue.Dequeue();
        for (int i = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(current) - 1; 0 <= i; i--)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(current, i);
            var typedChild = child as T;
            if (typedChild != null)
            {
                return typedChild;
            }
            queue.Enqueue(child);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What you are asking is really not clear. Please can you clarify

Comment: What did you try so far ? Can you show your code ?